# Why is a timestamp being added to the URL of a JavaScript resource?

Tags: javascript

```
$script.ready('jui',function() { 
$script('<?php base_path(); ?>js/partnerScripts.js?ts=1315442861','partners');
});
```

And why tag a fixed ts=timestamp? thing to the end of name of partnerScripts.js?
I search inside the folder but only found that file without the ts=xxxx. What's the purpose of that in the code. That number is fixed and it's like a real timestamp anyway?

Comment: The purpose would be [versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) I'd say.

Comment: Can you come up with better titles for your questions. This is two in a row that are entitled "The following javascript".

Comment: To help future readers, I believe he is asking "Why is a timestamp being added to this JS source file?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally done for "cache busting" on different versions.

If you want users to cache the script indefinitely, but still want to easily update it in the future, you just have to update the timestamp.  This effectively makes it a new URL/resource, but you can keep your files in the same place.

And yes, that timestamp is valid, and [is from September 2011](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).  It's the number of seconds since midnight, UTC, January 1, 1970.

Comment: +1 It's always good to know that clients will get the most up to date file while still being able to cache when appropriate :)